# How can I call the callback function after each string iteration?

Tags: jquery

I am using the jQuery libary type-it found here:http://macarthur.me/typeit/docs/

Here is my code

```
 $('.type-it').typeIt({
         strings: ['Text 1','Text 2'],
         speed: 110,
         breakLines: false,
         callback: function() { $('.type-it').css('background-color', '#EFC137').delay(1000).queue(function() {$('.type-it').empty() }) }
    })
    .tiPause(1000);
```

What I want to do is run the callback function after each string is typed rather than after all the strings are typed.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pj3frgtt/

Comment: the callback function is not triggered from each iteration I think from that library and it doesn't provide returned values, you will need to use an example a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: I want it to run after each iteration though.

Comment: Have you solved it?!

Comment: I haven't, Here is a code pen I am trying to work it out in : https://codepen.io/jocon128/pen/wJZVRq

Comment: Want I want to happen is for a string to be typed, then the span background colour changed to yellow and then deleted. I then want the next string to be typed and then do the same.

Comment: Issue I keep getting is it is typing the first string then, instantly deleting, then typing the second string with the background yellow. I have tried all sorts of timeouts and delays but can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the library doesn't support it, we can pass individual strings to the function. Here is a hack to do it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ara = ['Text 1', 'Text 2'].reverse();
  doType();

  function doType() {
    var x = ara.pop();
    $('.type-it').typeIt({
      strings: [x],
      speed: 110,
      breakLines: false,
      callback: function() {
        $('.type-it').css('background-color', '#EFC137').delay(2000).queue(function() {
          $('.type-it').empty();
          $('.type-it').css('background-color', 'transparent');
          if (ara.length > 0)
            doType();
        })
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.type-it {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.typeit/4.4.0/typeit.min.js"></script>
<div class="type-it"></div>
```

Comment: This is close to what I want however. Want I want to happen is for a string to be typed, then the span background colour changed to yellow and then deleted. I then want the next string to be typed and then do the same.