# Animate each line of textarea

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I want to animate each line of a textarea, without putting any breaks. Something like this (https://greensock.com/SplitText). Is this possible with jQuery (so no Greensock).

Best wishes

Comment: Not a bad question for me. So Votes up!

Comment: @Deadpool True thing!! Agreed!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Its Possible.

You can use https://macarthur.me/typeit/docs/ the typeIt library.

And in case you need some Css animation after each line, you can check out my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43222060/1907391

Remove the `.empty()` from the callback function.

Here is a snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ara = ['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3', 'Text 4', 'TypeIt is the most versatile jQuery animated typing plugin on the planet. In simple use, it allows you to type single or multiple strings that break lines, delete & replace each other, and it even handles HTML tags & entities.', 'For more advanced, controlled typing effects, TypeIt comes with companion functions that can be chained to control your typing down to the smallest character, enabling you to type an dynamic narrative, with complete control over speed, characters, line breaks, deletions, pausing, everything.'];
  doType();

  function doType() {
    //var x = ara.pop();
    $('.type-it').typeIt({
      strings: ara,
      speed: 110,
      breakLines: true,
      callback: function() {
        $('.type-it').delay(2000).queue(function() {})
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.type-it {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.typeit/4.4.0/typeit.min.js"></script>
<div class="type-it"></div>
```

You can find some other animation plugins here http://www.learningjquery.com/2016/06/12-jquery-plugins-to-animate-text

Answer (score 2):

You can animate individual words by creating sub elements for each word:

```js
$("#text").html(function () {
  return "<div>" + $(this).html().split(" ").join("</div><div>") + " </div>";
});

setTimeout(function (){
  $("#text div:nth-child(even)")
    .addClass("even",1000);
  $("#text div:nth-child(odd)")
      .addClass("odd",1000);
},2000);
```

```css
#text {
  height:3em;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#text div {
  float:left;
  margin-left:5px;
}

.even {
  margin-top:-2em;
}

.odd {
  margin-top:4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">
  This is a great text area.
</div>
```